# How to return just first parent element, but many children and grandchildren in Linq with Entity Framework - SYBASE ASE Connector bug

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sybase-ase15

I have the following Linq statement:

```
car car = db.cars
              .Include("wheels")
              .Include("windows")
              .Where(c => c.id == id)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

I have lazy loading turned off. I want to return a single car with several wheels and several windows, but this returns a one wheeled car with just one window. How can I return all the children in this query, whilst still returning just one car?

I should also note that this is a many-to-many relationship, so a wheel can be assigned to many cars.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't just one applicable wheel and window? I've just done the equivalent code about 5 minutes ago and it worked fine. What SQL query is it producing?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I have done several tests and have followed through carefully with debugger. I then try to do a delete and it fails if there is more than wheel for the car because of reference constraint error. I will have a look at the SQL now. Note that I am using Sybase Ase as a database (urgh!), so it could be a bug with the connector.

Comment: I wasn't even checking, I just had the same case in my own code, but it was using PostgreSQL via Npgsql.

Comment: Ah right, I am using the Sybase connector with Sybase ASE. I have not been able to find the SQL generated for this unfortunately. I do not have a profiler, may look into this.

Comment: Assing an `Action<string>` to `db.Database.Log` that logs the strings passed and you should be able to see the SQL generated that way.

Comment: Is this only supported by EF6? Sybase-ase is restricted to version 4.something of entity framework

Comment: Ah, alas it seems that `Log` was indeed added with EF4. A shame, since as you can imagine it's very useful at times like this.

Comment: I can imagine.. I'm dreaming of a day when my boss agrees that Sybase Ase needs to be replaced. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack to get around some Sybase Ase issues when used with the Sybase data connector, but this works:

```
var carSet = db.cars
              .Include("wheels")
              .Include("windows")
              .Where(c => c.id == id);

var car = carSet.FirstOrDefault();
```